# Android audio normalization or levelling

Tags: java, android, audio, normalization, volume

I have no experience with audio, and I ever only did one app for Android, and it was a log time ago, and it was simple form processing. However, I now have a particular need to do with audio processing, and wonder if anybody could give me some hints.

What I need is simply a clipping filter - a filter that could work with any audio player and would control the output (regardless whether it is then sent to e.g. earphones, blue tooth phones or the main speaker).   It should make sure that no sounds are above a certain loudness level, and those that are should be clipped.  That upper loudness limit should be adjustable, but once set, it should not be per-track, but set for everything that is producing the audio.

Please note that I do not mean normalization, where the entire track is made quieter, if there are spikes in it.  I do not want the volume level to be adjusted.  I want the volume level to stay at whatever the user sets it, except for the offending spikes.

I don't even care if such audio spikes are scaled down elegantly and still intelligible, or if they are simply and crudely clipped.  Scaling them down would be luxury, but clipping would be acceptable.

Thank you for any guidance or help.

Answer (score 2):

The process that you are describing is commonly referred to as **limiting** by audio engineers. See the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting) for more information on the process and its best practices.

Though my Android development experience is a bit thin, I have had great luck with the Superpowered framework. It contains [audio dynamics processors](http://superpowered.com/compressor-limiter-clipper#limiter), including a soft-knee limiter (called Superpowered Limiter) and a hard-knee limiter (called Superpowered Clipper.)